# Find, prune and delete files under Linux

Tags: linux, script, file-management

```
find . -path '/mnt/ftp/ben/brc' -prune -o -iregex '.*\.\(docx\|xls\|txt\|pdf\|xlsm\|doc\|xlsx\|CVS\|csv\)$'  -mtime +730  -delete
```

I need all docx, xls, txt, xlms, doc files older than 2 years from my ftp server but also want to exclude `/mnt/ftp/ben/brc` directory. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
find . -path '/mnt/ftp/ben/brc' -prune -o -iregex '.*\.\(docx\|xls\|txt\|pdf\|xlsm\|doc\|xlsx\|CVS\|csv\)$'  -mtime +730  -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: find . -path '/mnt/ftp/ben/brc' -prune -o -iregex '.*\.\(docx\|xls\|txt\|pdf\|xlsm\|doc\|xlsx\|CVS\|csv\)$'  -mtime +730  -print0 | xargs -0 rm
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information